# Where can I download Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

I am unable to find the link for downloading Ubuntu 16.04 onto my   desktop/laptop. I am able to see the link only for 18.04, but I need 16.04.

Comment: Try one of the links here : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Comment: On the download page "For other versions of Ubuntu Desktop including torrents, the network installer, a list of local mirrors, and **past releases** see our alternative downloads."

Answer (score 5):

There are many download options listed in the main download page: http://ubuntu.com/download, which include **Alternative downloads**.

The top two lines of the **Main Download** page has menu items of important links about Ubuntu and the available download options.

For the LTS versions, from the main download link [Ubuntu LTS Download](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (the link you are most likely referring to in your question), look for the [see our alternative downloads.](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) link.  You'll find it under the **Download** icon on the page.

The other supported versions, including 16.04 will always have their direct download link listed.

Note: **Alternative Downloads**, **Ubuntu flavours** and other download choices are also linked in the Link menu just below **Main** menu string that referrs to ohter important links about Ubuntu.